# Как составить классы в соответствии с UML диаграммой?

Tags: java, наследование, инкапсуляция

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Методы не должны иметь реализаций и должны возвращать, в случае необходимости, базовые значения.
Классы не должны содержать конструкторов.

Базовые значения для целых - 0,

для строк - "",

для boolean - true

Спецификация к  UML:

"-" private

"+" public

"#" protected

Набросал вот такую вещь, но почему-то выдает ошибки. Подскажите, где что не так делаю?

```
    abstract class Employee {
protected  String name;
protected Integer ID, salary;

public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
protected void work(){
        }
    }
     class Manager extends Employee {
private Long time;
private BigInteger projectMoney;
private Byte countOfPaper;

 public void throwPaper(){
 }
    class Programmer extends Employee {
        private String task;
        private Integer stamina;
        private String code;
        public void coding(String task){
      Employee coding = new Programmer();
    }
    public void test(String code){
     Programmer test = new Programmer();
    }
    public void Fix(String code){
       Programmer test = new Programmer();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> но почему-то выдает ошибки.

Никогда не говорите, какие это ошибки. Мы сами угадаем.

В классе `Manager` не хватает закрывающей `}`. Так что класс `Programmer` попал внутрь класса `Manager`.

Первые два метода класса `Programmer` должны что-то возвращать.

Это зачем? -

```
Programmer test = new Programmer();
```

Comment: Ошибки следующего вида:

Comment: Compilation error
Main.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        Employee e22 = new Programmer();
                           ^
  symbol:   class Programmer
  location: class Main
Main.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
        Programmer e2 = new Programmer();
        ^
  symbol:   class Programmer
  location: class Main
Main.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
        Programmer e2 = new Programmer();
                            ^
  symbol:   class Programmer
  location: class Main
3 errors

Comment: @СанСаныч Ну и где в вопросе код с переменной `e22`?

Comment: когда поправил скобку, ошибка стала другой: Compilation error
Main.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
        e2.fix("code");
          ^
  symbol:   method fix(String)
  location: variable e2 of type Programmer
1 error

Comment: Все! Спасибо! Разобрался!!!

Comment: @СанСаныч Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Как всегда все проблемы были из-за невнимательности и спешки)))